# Joomla Cache creates lots of cache files; how to manage cache properly.

Tags: caching, plugins, joomla

I am using Joomal 3.3. and  its hosted on the Godaddy and Godaddy's account file limit is 2500000. My Joomla is creating large amount cache files which goes over the limit. The website is a calendar driven and has lots of events, quires based on categories, etc. I have been cleaning cache manually. First, I would like to know why there are lots of cache files created and second I would appreciate any **suggestion/solution** that will **resolve this issue permanently**. Is there any **plugin** that would automatically clear the cache like every two days which I should I consider?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is the expired cache that should be deleted, but is not. You should purge the expired cache automatically by adding the following to your cron:

```
wget http://yourwebsite.com/cli/garbagecron.php
```

The above cron should preferably run on a daily basis. If you don't know how to add it, then you can always ask your host (GoDaddy) to do it for you.